# How check all items of array contains substring

Tags: arrays, powershell, contains

```
$substring="s0306"
$WScript = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$lnk=Get-ChildItem -Path "$ENV:userprofile\desktop\*.lnk" | ForEach-Object {$WScript.CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath}
```

need to write true only if all elements $lnk contains $substring.

Comment: Make sure you tag this with the appropriate programming language, My best guess is powershell?

Comment: yes, powershell